# Showing that if $f = 0$ whenever $f=0$ on $\Omega \subset X$ then $\Omega$ is dense in $X$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm trying to solve this exercise in the lecture notes for a course in analysis that I'm taking. [image]

Proving that that defines a seminorm is straightforward. I'm only stuck in the step where I have to show that if the seminorm is in fact a norm (that is $v_\Omega(f) = 0$ implies $f \equiv 0$) then $\Omega$ is dense in $X$.

In the case where $X$ is $T4$ I know I can use Urysohn's Lemma to get a function $f$ that is zero on $\overline{\Omega}$ but takes the vAlue $1$ on some chosen point in $X$ outside of it and so I'd be done. However I don't see how to cook up such a function in the general compact Hausdorff case.

Comment: A compact Hausdorff space is actually always $T_4$ and Urysohn applies.

Comment: Ah okay I wasn’t aware of that. Thanks!